# Find $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $a_n (\max_{1 \leq i\leq n}X_{i} - b_n)$ converges in distribution to a non-degenerate random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ be iid with the same chi-square distribution with one degree of freedom. Find $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $a_n (\max_{1 \leq i\leq n}X_{i} - b_n)$ converges in distribution to a non-degenerate random variable.

**Comments:** I proved an inequality $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{t}{1+t^2}\exp({-\frac{t^2}{2}}) \leq P(|X| \geq t) \leq \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{1}{t}\exp({-\frac{t^2}{2}})$ in the first part of the question, which I believe could be useful here, but I don't know how to apply here. I've seen several such questions so I appreciate any ideas or solutions to this type of questions.

Comment: Use $P(M_n\le t_n)=(1-P(X>t_n))^n\to \exp(-nP(X>t_n))$ where $t_n=t/a_n+b_n$.

Comment: @A.S. Thanks! Then, I just need to calculate the exp? It seems the inequality is not used here.

Comment: It's used, for you need to "stabilize" $nP(X>t_n)$ and to do that, you need to use asymptotics of $P(X>t_n)$ that you derived.

Comment: @A.S. $(1-P(X>t_n))^n\to \exp(-nP(X>t_n))$? Are you letting $n$ go to infinity? And you still have $n$ in $\exp(-nP(X>t_n))$ after it goes to infinity?

Comment: @top $a_n\to b_n$ means $a_n-b_n\to 0$ in this case.

Comment: Using standard conventions and the notation $$T_n=a_n\left(\max\limits_{1 \leqslant i\leqslant n}X_i - b_n\right),$$ the first comment means $$P(T_n\leqslant t)=(1-P(X>b_n+t/a_n))^n\to\exp\left(-\lim_{k\to\infty}kP(X>b_k+t/a_k)\right).$$